# Kentico CMS - open URL in specific browser

Tags: google-chrome, url, content-management-system, kentico

I am new to Kentico CMS and expect that my question can be answered easily by somebody in the know!

Basically the default web browser we use at work is IE but we have a web app that only supports Chrome, we have linked the web page but I am not sure how to force it to open in Chrome.

Thanks for any assistance!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to force user to open your link in a particular browser. How open a web links is a OS setting. For example, in Window 10 you can see/change it in Settings->Apps->Default apps-> Web browser

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific in Kentico in which you can force a user to open a URL in a specific browser.  BUT what you can do is create a URL shortcut on the desktop with the Chrome browser application which will allow the user to double click the Chrome icon and open the URL in Chrome.

To do this, simply open the URL you want to make a shortcut to in the Chrome browser.  Click and drag the "I" or the padlock on to the desktop and your shortcut will be created.